# Best way to kill process itself and all child processesg

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, fork, kill, child-process

I am newbie. My program creates some amount of child processes during lifetime using system call `fork()`. I need to handle interrupt signal for parent and in it's handler kill all child processes that have been created during program runtime.
I have tried following code ...

```
setpgrp(0,0);
$SIG{INT} = \&kill_all;
sub kill_all() {
     print "Going to kill child processes \n";
     kill -9, getpgrp();
}
....
fork()..
....
fork()...
....
fork()
.....
```

But it seems that not all processes are killed , please suggest the right way to do this.

Comment: Side note: you really shouldn't be using `kill -9` unless you absolutely have to. It's like ripping the power cord out of the wall instead of running `shutdown`. Give your child processes a chance to clean up after themselves and exit gracefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off - don't `kill -9`. That's bad practice unless you absolutely have to. `SIGTERM` or `-15` is much nicer.

To send things to your process group, the easiest approach is (from `perlipc`: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals)

`kill -$$`

> Sending a signal to a negative process ID means that you send the signal to the entire Unix process group.

Alternatively - `fork` returns a pid. You can explicitly kill that pid.

If you're having problems with children not exiting in response to kill signals though, then the most common problem is that they've entered an uninterruptible state.

This might be something like IO on an NFS mount (or other IO to device that's unavailable). Unfortunately this is an OS specific problem, which isn't solvable via perl. You can check this by running `ps -e v` and check for the 'state' flag.

```
state    The state is given by a sequence of characters, for example, "RWNA". The      first character indicates the run state of the process:
D    Marks a process in disk (or other short term, uninterruptible) wait.
I    Marks a process that is idle (sleeping for longer than about 20 seconds).  
L    Marks a process that is waiting to acquire a lock.
R    Marks a runnable process.
S    Marks a process that is sleeping for less than about 20 seconds.
T    Marks a stopped process.
W    Marks an idle interrupt thread.
Z    Marks a dead process (a "zombie").
```

Either that or they've become zombie processes, and are waiting to be reaped. You can avoid this by setting `$SIG{'CHLD'} = "IGNORE";` 
But as noted in the comments - you shouldn't do this *as well* as killing by fork-pid, because of the race condition it creates.

You should also note - if you configure a signal handler, and *then* `fork`, then the forked child also has that handler. You may need to remove it again in the child process.

Comment: "fork returns a pid. You can explicitly kill that pid." There's a dangerous race condition here. If the child exits before you try to kill it and another process gets the same PID, you end up killing the other process.

Comment: `ps -o pid,ppid,pgrp,sid,stat,cmd` would also show process group, so you can verify if the process you want to kill actually belongs to the process group you signaled.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, That's not true. The PID won't be released until the process is reaped using `wait`/`waitpid`. (Keep in mind that `$SIG{CHLD}='IGNORE';` auto-reaps.)

Comment: Which is a good point - if you turn that on, then you potentially introduce the race condition.

Comment: One of the advantageous features of a zombie. It's a good way to be sure that your process has actually exited (or not). In addition to being a placeholder for retrieving a return code.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly I am getting message from all childs . $SIG{'CHLD'} = "IGNORE"; has been already set. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry , but if to do as you suggested , it will left processes in background ...  What can be wrong, or I should manually collect pids into array and than iterate through it and kill all processes.

Comment: What state are your processes in? You've _sent_ them all the signal. They're just not acting on it. Check the state flags, and you'll see (probably) why.

Comment: If I am not mistaken , forked(new) process  uses parent signal handlers  , so I have simply set $SIG{INT} = 'DEFAULT';  in all forks in my program and it seems to work.

Comment: Ah yes. `fork` means processes inherit _everything_ including signal handlers etc. But that shouldn't apply to the `KILL` signal you were originally sending.